# Internet Explorer no LogIn or add to Cart possible - appears only in https: - Session loss ? 1.9.2.3

Tags: internet-explorer, session-cookies, magento-1.9

We have a Magento 1.9.2.3. Installment on our Server. If u browse our Site with Mozilla, Chrome, Safari everything works fine. If u browse with Internet Explorer or Opera, no Login or go to Checkout is possible. So everytime when i switch to https.(suggestion) There are some possible solutions for this i tried:

Increase Cookie Lifetime due to the servertime-issue. -> Increased to 1 day ( 86400 sec.)

SessionData saved over Database , SessionData saved over Filesave , both ways wont solve the issue.

i asked our provider if other customers had similar issues with the SSL -> no such problems

set cookiedomain to : .site.de , this only leads to that the other browsers also have the issue, so i cant login or checkout in any browser then.

Between every step i cleaned Cache/Session of the server AND the browser.

commented (*/) CookieParams in Varien.php - no success

Well, im pretty much out of ideas now. Please excuse my bad english.

Thank you for your folowing ideas,

Greetings